# Unbiased estimator in no-intercept regression model

Tags: regression, unbiased-estimator

On an assignment I've been tasked with finding whether
$$\hat{\beta}_1=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2},$$
the estimator for the slope of a no-intercept regression model $Y_i=\beta_1 X_i+\epsilon_i$, is unbiased. I'm not sure how this is done. I would like to use the traditional expected value definition $\mathbb{E}(\hat{A})=A$, but I encounter trouble at the beginning with

$$\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}\right),$$

given that (at least from what I've seen),

$$\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}\right) \neq \frac{\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i\right)}{\mathbb{E}(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2)}.$$

As such, I'm stuck. We haven't learned about the [Gauss-Markov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem) (so [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2944479/proof-verification-tilde-beta-1-is-an-unbiased-estimator-of-beta-1-obta) couldn't be used here) or [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality), and we are not given the distribution of $X_i$ nor told to treat $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$ as constant.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not matter whether the $X_i$ are random or fixed (so long as the probability they are all zero is $0$).

$$\mathbb E \left[ \frac{\sum X_iY_i}{\sum X_i^2}\right] =  \mathbb E \left[ \frac{\sum bX_i^2 +X_i \epsilon_i}{\sum X_i^2}\right]=  \mathbb E \left[b\frac {\sum X_i^2}{\sum X_i^2}\right]  + \sum\mathbb E\left[\frac{ X_i }{\sum X_i^2}\epsilon_i\right] \\=b+0=b$$ using the independence of the $\epsilon_i$ from the $X_i$ and $\mathbb E \left[ \epsilon_i\right]=0$.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. Clearly I faced the classic beginner mixup between $X_i$ and $x_i$...

Answer (score 2):

You don't need these theorems. $x_i$ is deterministic, and we have $y_i=\beta_1x_i+\epsilon_i$.
So just substitute $y_i$ in the numerator with the above formula.
Now just take expectation. The key is to just note that $x_i$ and $y_i$ are deterministic values and only $\epsilon_i$'s are random variables.

Answer (score 2):

A major point is that the $x_i$ are NOT RANDOM and the $Y_i$ are random. (Note that below, I do not confuse $Y_i$ with $y_i$. The latter is an observed value; the former is a random variable.) So
\begin{align}
\operatorname E\left( \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_iY_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} \right) & = \frac{\operatorname E\left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i Y_i \right)}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} \text{ because the $x$s are not random} \\[10pt]
& = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname E(x_iY_i) }{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} \text{ by linearity of expectation} \\[10pt]
& = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\operatorname E(Y_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} \text{ because the $x$s are not random} \\[10pt]
& = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \big( \beta_1 x_i\big)}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} \\[10pt]
& = \frac{\beta_1 \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \big( x_i\big)}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} \Large{ \begin{smallmatrix} \text{because $\beta_1$ does not} \\ \text{change as $i$ goes from $1$ to $n$} \end{smallmatrix}} \\[10pt]
& = \beta_1.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Explanatory variables $x_i$s are *assumed* to be known, fixed values. The randomness emanates from $\boldsymbol\varepsilon.$ Any linear estimator would be of the form $\mathbf c^\top\mathbf Y= \sum_i c_iY_i.$

If $\mathbb E[\sum_i c_iY_i]=\beta_1,$
this means $\sum c_ix_i=1.$ Imposing additional constraints and requirements for the estimator (viz. BLUE) would lead to particular value of $\mathbf c. $